# HTML/SVG: Download on click

Tags: html, css, svg, download, click

Currently I'm using SVG for some animation and I want that when someone clicks on an image with SVG around it that it will start a download for that image.

```
<div class="box">
  <svg width="100%" height="100%">
      ....
  </svg>
  <a href="chief.png" download="chief.png"><img src="chief.png" alt="Chief"/></a>
</div>
```

How do I change it so it starts a download on click?

Answer (score 0):

Test this

```
<a href="http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/">
  <svg class="Orange" ... >
    <use xlink:href="buttonB.svg#Root"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

and check this page > http://tavmjong.free.fr/SVG/BUTTON_TEST/button_test.html

Comment: Hi. Welcome to S.O. This answers half of the question. It doesn't explain how to force the image to download. EDIT: Actually OP seems to be using `download="chief.png"` which will work in some browsers but your answer removes that. It would be useful, for this person and future readers, if the answer doesn't undo what is in the given code and instead solves the  problem as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

When the SVG is wrapped with the anchor, a click event on the SVG will be sent up to the anchor. In this case that will trigger the download.

```
<div class="box">
    <a href="chief.png" download="chief.png">
        <svg width="100%" height="100%">
          ....
        </svg>
    </a>
</div>
```